# How to Pinch Zoom on device with no touchscreen, like an Android Stick?

Tags: browser, zooming

I have some Android TV "sticks", such as the RK3188, which is basically a tablet minus the screen. You control them using keyboard and a mouse.

The problem is, I have no way to zoom in or out in the browser. There's no way for me to do a "pinch" gesture, and Ctrl +/- etc. don't seem to work in any browser, like Chrome, FireFox, and Dolphin.

I'm using the box as a display screen in a public area and not being able to scale the content to fit the whole TV is a serious limitation.

EDIT: Double tap only offers 2 zoom levels "close" and "far".

Comment: Have you tried doubleclicking the webpage? Doubletap in Android is usually interpreted as a zooming gesture.

Comment: some computers allow you to left and right click at the same time and drag to zoom

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just found this info with a quick google http://www.pcworld.com/article/184656/android_keyboard_shortcuts.html

I hope it helps.

Android Keyboard Shortcuts: Browsing

• Menu + I: Zoom in

• Menu + O: Zoom out

• Menu + J: Go back a page

• Menu + K: Go forward a page

• Menu + R: Refresh current page

• Menu + F: Find on page

• Menu + B: Open bookmarks

• Menu + S: Open social network sharing menu

• Menu + H: View browsing history

• Menu + S: Open browser settings

Answer (score 1):

As aureljared points out, apps offer alternative zoom mechanisms. Google officially recommends that apps use either double-click or double-click-and-drag to zoom. (That is, click once, then hold the mouse button down and drag vertically to zoom in and out.)

Android's "manifest" system for apps requires apps to state explicitly if they work with non-touchscreen pointing interfaces like a mouse, joystick, or trackpad. If the manufacturer of your TV stick set it up correctly, it will only show you apps which can be used **fully** with a mouse and keyboard, including zooming.

Answer (score 1):

This way works for me - double klick with left mouse button and hold it down at second klick, then drag up or down to zoom in or out.