# Can anybody pinch-zoom a PDF document using external touchpad/trackpad on an Android TV box?

Tags: pdf, touch, zooming, gestures

Android doesn't seem to support external touchpad (usb or wireless) pinch gesture for zooming in and out?

I tried a few external wireless keyboards with touchpads built-in, while the touchpad works for pinch on Mac and Windows, it didn't work for pinch-zooming on Android.

So my guess it's not possible. I use my Android TV box (BuzzTV box, Android 9) as an Android desktop for apps e.g. PDF reader.

Also tried using normal mouse, scroll wheel and ALT or CTRL or whatever combination it is typically..

I understand Android 14 has support for external keyboards but I don't see mentioned whether it also provides pinch zoom gestures for external touchpads. Not planning to upgrade the TV box yet.

To solve the external keyboard compatibility, there is an app called External Keyboard Helper for Android. That solves the keyboard issue.

But I can't find anything similar that would allow me to use pinch/zoom on external touchpad.

Some apps have support for keyboard shortcuts (Alt+leftButton+arrowRight/arrowLeft works for me), but most apps do not support this.

The issue is not related to this specific tv box. I tried other brands TV boxes and it is the same problem.

Is it a universal Android limitation?

UPDATE: Here I found some answer.. But I am still looking for a way to pinch zoom a PDF.  So I guess my question needs to be - is there any app for PDF that supports pinch and zoom natively on non-touchscreen pointing interfaces?

[How to Pinch Zoom on device with no touchscreen, like an Android Stick?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/82062/how-to-pinch-zoom-on-device-with-no-touchscreen-like-an-android-stick)

Answer (score 1):

Most combination keyboard and touchpad units don't actually tell Android about their touchpad (i.e. by reporting exactly where the user's fingers are, etc.). Instead they do their own gesture recognition and then send mouse input to Android instead. For example, they might report scroll wheel movements when you swipe with two fingers on the pad. This means that for those touchpads, you can't use any gestures that aren't programmed into the touchpad's firmware. It's likely that the keyboard/touchpad combos you tried are doing this.

You can tell that a touchpad is identifying itself properly (i.e. sending touch locations rather than mouse events) by doing the following:

- On Android 9, when you make the pinch-zoom gesture on the touchpad you should see two white spots on the screen corresponding to the locations of your fingers.
- On Android 14, connect your touchpad to the Android device and then go to Settings > System. You should see a section called "Touchpad".

If the touchpad identifies itself properly, then pinch-zoom gestures should work on either Android 9 or 14. Since you asked specifically about PDFs, I just tried pinch-zooming on the Apple Magic Trackpad (which does identify itself properly) with a PDF open in Firefox on Android 14, and it worked.